# which folder python 2.6 is installed in centos 6.5

Tags: python, centos6.5

Actually I installed python 2.6 in CentOS 6.5 and want to run a command on start up time in CentOS 6.5. I installed watchdog also so that can monitor activity for a folder printing located at /var/www/html/printing.

Previously I did this in Windows 8.1 from .bat file and write a command to run script written below

> c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\check_directory1.py c:\printing

In my CentOS 6.5 printing folder is located at /var/www/html/printing

how to write a command that can locate python.exe windows like file in CentOS and how to run that command at start-up...?

can any one help me on this...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch perl script on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518802/launch-perl-script-on-startup)

Comment: k
thanks
i will check it

Comment: `which python` should get you the location of python.

Comment: thanks a lot

this helps me